# Find the gaps for given date range in mysql, having multiple joins

Tags: mysql, date, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I have four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `AID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `BID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DtStart` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DtStop` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `AID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `CID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FLAGS` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `D` (
  `DID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DID`)
);
```

I'm feeding data like this,

```
INSERT INTO A (Name) VALUES ("First");
INSERT INTO C (FLAGS) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO B (DtStart, DtStop, AID, CID) VALUES ("2016-09-07", "2017-09-07", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO D (CID, Name) VALUES (1, "Alan");
INSERT INTO C (FLAGS) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO B (DtStart, DtStop, AID, CID) VALUES ("2016-09-15", "2017-09-23", 1, 2);
INSERT INTO D (CID, Name) VALUES (2, "John");
```

When I hit the query:

```
SELECT 
    A.Name as Object, B.DtStart, B.DtStop, C.FLAGS, D.Name as User
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.AID=A.AID
    LEFT JOIN C ON C.CID=B.CID
    LEFT JOIN D ON D.CID=C.CID
WHERE "2017-09-01" <= B.DtStop AND "2017-10-01" > B.DtStart;
```

I get the result:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
| Object | DtStart             | DtStop              | FLAGS | User |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
| First  | 2016-09-07 00:00:00 | 2017-09-07 00:00:00 |     1 | Alan |
| First  | 2016-09-15 00:00:00 | 2017-09-23 00:00:00 |     2 | John |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How could I find all the rows which also include gaps for the given date range?

In my example, I'm looking for the report (**Sep 1, 2017** to **Sep 30, 2017**) so I want result like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
| Object | DtStart             | DtStop              | FLAGS | User |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
| First  | 2016-09-07 00:00:00 | 2017-09-07 00:00:00 |     1 | Alan |
| First  | 2017-09-08 00:00:00 | 2017-09-14 00:00:00 |  NULL | NULL |
| First  | 2016-09-15 00:00:00 | 2017-09-23 00:00:00 |     2 | John |
| First  | 2016-09-24 00:00:00 | 2017-09-30 00:00:00 |  NULL | NULL |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is just models of my original tables, I have multiple joins over 10 tables in my query

Comment: BTW, B is an INNER JOIN

Comment: Try to used "Left outer join" not just "left join"

Comment: I think for mysql "Left outer join" and "left join" both are same.

Comment: in the second row of the report table, should dtStart is same as preceding DtStop **but** the fourth row  ('2016-09-24') is after the preceding DStop.

Comment: oh, yes! @Used_By_Already, It is a mistake. In the second row, the year should be 2017 instead of 2016. Let me correct it.